# How to change TabLayout.Tab's icon when the tab is selected?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How to change TabLayout.Tab's icon when the tab is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_live_stream_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_live_stream_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_live_stream_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_live_stream_default" />
</selector>
```